# correct use of functor for C++ STL thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, functor

I'm having some difficulty understanding the correct usage of a functional object as a thread routine in C++ STL.  From my understanding, one of the benefits of a functor is that the object instance can maintain state.  There are times when I want one or more threads to run some routine and compute some result.  I then query those results from the objects after I have joined the threads.  I'm trying to do the same with C++ STL threads and running into some problems.  It appears the problem stems from the fact that the C++ STL thread makes a copy of my object and thus I'm not sure how I'm supposed to go about inspecting the results when I join the threads.  Here's a snippet of the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

class Worker
{
public:
    Worker() : _value(0)
    {
    }

    void operator()(unsigned int value);

    unsigned int get_value() {return this->_value;}

private:
    unsigned int _value;
};

void Worker::operator()(unsigned int value)
{
    this->_value = value;
}

int main()
{
    Worker worker;
    thread thread(worker, 13);
    thread.join();
    unsigned int value = worker.get_value();
    cout << "value: " << value << endl;
}
```

The above example is just a simple repro of the problem I'm running into.  I would expect worker.get_value() to return 13 yet it's returning zero.  How do I go about instantiating an object with state, having a thread run a routine in that object, and then query the state of that object after the thread has completed?

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you pass by value you make a copy. So you can pass by reference through reference wrapper:

```
thread thread(std::ref(worker), 13);
```

or pass by pointer:

```
thread thread(&worker, 13);
```

in both cases you have to make sure that object lifetime is long enough.

Answer (score 4):

Don't make a copy, but instead bind the thread to a reference:

```
thread thread(std::ref(worker), 13);
//            ^^^^^^^^
```