# Read/Write information to class in another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

maybe I'm completely lost but I'm trying to learn threads in c++ and this code is not working quite well:

The relevant code is

```
TEST_F(TestSimulation, run_could_be_closed) {
    sim::Simulation simulation;
    std::thread thread(simulation);
    while (simulation.getCount() < 15000) {
        // wait
    }
    simulation.dispose();
}
```

```
void sim::Simulation::run() {  
    while (isRunning) {
        std::cout << "Processing information" << std::endl;
        count++;
    }
}

void sim::Simulation::dispose() {
    isRunning = false;
}

int sim::Simulation::getCount() {
    return count;
}
void sim::Simulation::operator()() {
    init();
    run();
}
```

Seems that the Thread class creates a copy of the object sent as parameter, so when I call `simulation.getCount()` in main thread, it always returns 0.

When I try to pass as reference `std::thread thread(&simulation);` I get an error

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/thread:336:5: error: attempt to use a deleted function
    __invoke(_VSTD::move(_VSTD::get<1>(__t)), _VSTD::move(_VSTD::get<_Indices>(__t))...);
```

What I want is to be able to writing and reading data to the object while is running inside the thread. Is this the way to go?

Comment: Please provide simulation code. As sidenote, "What I want is to be able to writing and reading data to the object while is running inside the thread. Is this the way to go?" Depends on workload which You did not specify. What you really have to understand is how threads work and performance tradeoffs. These are IMO best learned on lowest level - assembly.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42894629/correct-use-of-functor-for-c-stl-thread

Comment: There are a lot of things to be aware of when writing threaded code, particularly proper synchronization between threads. I'm assuming that your problem in particular is that you're copying the simulation, and the thread is working with a copy, but there are still other issues with synchronization that can cause undefined behavior from both threads using `count`.

Comment: Edited! As you may know, is a simplification to do not write a lot of code.

Comment: @mukunda I edited my post. When I try to pass as reference I get an error. What I interpret is that passing as reference has been marked as deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::thread thread(&simulation);` thread initialization error

Here is a similar example

```cpp
class Simulation {
public:
    Simulation() : count(0), isRunning(true) {}

    void Simulation::run() {
        while (isRunning) {
            std::cout << "Processing information" << std::endl;
            count++;
        }
    }

    void Simulation::dispose() { isRunning = false; }

    int Simulation::getCount() { return count; }

private:
    int count;
    bool isRunning;
}

int mian() {

    Simulation simulation;
    std::thread thread(&Simulation::run, &simulation);
    while (simulation.getCount() < 15) {
        // wait
    }
    simulation.dispose();
    simulation.join();
    cout << simulation.getCount() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The example section of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread demonstrates how to pass a class' member function and a reference to an instance of that class to a `std::thread`. See `std::thread t5(&foo::bar, &f);` in that sample coding.

This way you should be able to share one instance of `sim::Simulation` from your sample coding between the two threads. *BUT* this will open doors for all kinds of synchronization problems and races on the shared object/fields. So take care when you go beyond sharing just an `count`, which I presume is from an atomicly writable type.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Now thread is working I could start learning about the problems with multithreading and access to resources